# Problem with installing Node.JS on Windows

Tags: javascript, python, windows, node.js, cygwin

I'm trying to install Node.JS on Windows 7 with help of [this](http://blog.dtrejo.com/how-to-install-nodejs-on-windows) tutorial.
I downloaded Cygwin, installed it. I have installed Python 2.7.
After this i downloaded last version of Node.JS in tar.gz. Than I opened cygwin bash and typed this command there:

```
tar zxvf node<tab>
```

It unzipped it to directory: node-v0.4.2
But what i need to do if i have python installed?

I tried to type:

```
make test
```

and got error message: make: command not found

I will be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install all the [required packages](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29)? Run setup.exe again and check.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that the environment variables in Cygwin need to be configured:

[Getting Make to place nice with Cygwin](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~rgrimm/teaching/fa05-oop/windows-make.html)